# Writing "text" and Resource ID in Android

Tags: java, android, text, titlebar

How do I combine values from each source as mentioned say for example I want to change the titlebar value...

```
 page.setTitle(R.id.pagetitle)
```

Combine with...

```
 page.setTitle("a text")
```

In order to output...

```
 "R.id.pagetitle: a text" (note the " : ")
```

What is used in Java to connect these values like " **.** " in *PHP* or " **+** " in *JavaScript*?

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.Format

```
String myString = String.Format("%s: a title", getText(R.id.pagetitle));
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple.

```
String titleText = firstText.concat("a text");
page.setTitle(titleText);
```

Hope it helps.